# Android - spinner in action bar - layout file

Tags: android, android-actionbar, spinner

I am trying to implement a spinner in a actionbar.

I have the following in my activity onCreate():

```
SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.action_list, R.layout.spinner_item);
```

The action_list is defined as (res/values/arrays.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string-array name="action_list">
      <item>Layout 1</item>
      <item>Layout 2</item>
      <item>Layout 3</item>
  </string-array>
</resources>
```

The spinner_item is defined as (res/layouts/spinner_item.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am getting the following exception :

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast 
 to android.widget.TextView 
 at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
```

Can anyone help me resolve this ? what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way to fix this is to have `spinner_item.xml` contain a single `TextView`.

The default implementation of `ArrayAdapter` fills a `TextView` with the string value of the corresponding item.

This `TextView` can be the whole view, or a particular view in a layout, but for this last case you need to pass the view id as a parameter (see for example the [`ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int%29) constructor.